# Indicators running but not showing on bar

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel, ubuntu

I've been looking everywhere but I can't find a solution to my problem:
Somehow I did something that dissabled the indicators on the wingpanel of my ElementaryOS 0.4 Loki (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).

I've removed and installed pantheon, wingpanel, the indicator and tried so many solutions that I found arround the internet but nothing fixed my problem.

I'm trying to install indicator-cpufreq, and even it is installed and running (I've looking for it on system monitor) It isn't on the top bar.
The default icons and indicators are showed and working perfect, but I can't add more than it.

Thank you,
Yeray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not done anything wrong. The developers have decided not enable 3rd-party indicators from Loki onward, and are discussing what the solution for such apps should be.

If I find a workaround, I will post it here.